# Async/Await in recursive Javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, async-await

I am new to NodeJS and kind of an amateur at Javascript. I have written a recursive function called 'maskFields' that goes through a very **LARGE** Json object with many properties and sub-properties, and checks which fields in the Json object are "sensitive data" by checking them against the second parameter, an array of strings. If a field in the Json object exists in the array, then it is a sensitive field, and I mask it's value with asterisks. I want this function to run ASYNCHRONOUSLY, and this is how I've tried to do it:

```
function isEmpty(value) {
  return (value == null || (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0));
}

async function maskFields(jsonObject, fieldsToMask) {
    if (typeof jsonObject === 'object' && jsonObject !== null) {
        if (Array.isArray(jsonObject)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
                jsonObject[i] = await maskFields(jsonObject[i], fieldsToMask);
            }
        } else {
            for (const key in jsonObject) {
                if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    jsonObject[key] = await maskFields(jsonObject[key], fieldsToMask);
                    if (fieldsToMask.includes(key) && !isEmpty(jsonObject[key])){
                        if(typeof jsonObject[key] !== "string")
                        {
                            jsonObject[key] = String(jsonObject[key]);
                        }
                        var data = jsonObject[key].substring(0, 1);
                        var maskedChar = '*'.repeat(jsonObject[key].length - 1);
                        var output = data + maskedChar;
                        jsonObject[key] = output;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return jsonObject; **//THIS IS COMING BACK COMPLETELY EMPTY!**
}
```

As you can see, the first parameter to the recursive function maskFields, 'jsonObject' is the LARGE Json object I am recursively iterating through, and the second parameter 'fieldstoMask' is the array that contains the sensitive keys whose values need to be masked. If the jsonObject contains a sensitive field that exists in 'fieldsToMask', my code will mask it with asterisks. In the end, I want to return the JSON object with all sensitive fields masked.

**HOWEVER**, the jsonObject being returned is completely empty. If I remove the async/await, it works fine and returns what I want. Obviously, I am doing something wrong with the async and await. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: how does the jsonObject look like?

Comment: @sid like this let jsonObject= {
  "Applicant": {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "MiddleInitial": "B",
    "LastName": "Kepler",
    "FullName": null,
    "Addr1": "123 Main Street",
    "Addr2": "Apt 202",
    "City": "Toronto",
    "State": "OH",
    "PostalCode": "44109",
    "SSN": "123456789",
    "DateOfBirth": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "HomePhoneAreaCode": "123",
  } But this is only a small part of it. It has many other parent fields and child fields.

Comment: What is the point of using `async/await` here when there appears to be NO asynchronous code that uses promises at all?  `await` is pointless if you don't have an actual asynchronous operation that uses a promise.  `await` does not make synchronous code into asynchronous code.  If that's your premise here, then that is just wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 Like I said, I am very new to NodeJS and a beginner at Javascript. How would I make this function asynchronous with Promises?

Comment: You can't make synchronous code run asynchronously in Javascript unless you put it in a WorkerThread or a child process.  This code is all synchronous.  No amount of `await` will change it from synchronous code to asynchronous code.  `await` is only useful to manage operations that are ALREADY fundamentally asynchronous and already use promises.

Comment: Works fine with any of the test data I've thrown at it. No point in it being asynchronous though.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen But if I WANTED this function to be asynchronous, how would I go about it?

Comment: @jfriend00 How do I make this recursive function run asynchronously with Promises? I have done some research on my own but it has not helped so far

Comment: I've already answered you.  The only way to make synchronous code run in a non-blocking way is to move it to another thread or process using a WorkerThread or put it into a child_process and then use messaging to communicate back the result.  Javascript does not allow you to write from scratch asynchronous code yourself.  All existing asynchronous operations in nodejs have a core implementation in native code that either uses natively asynchronous OS APIs (like networking) or uses threads (like file I/O) to give it an asynchronous appearance to your Javascript.

Comment: @Rocker2982 please what is your objective in having your code be "asynchronous"? What do you expect? Sounds like there is a misconception here.

Comment: You may be under a misapprehension what exactly "asynchonous" means in context of JavaScript? Can you explain what you want to happen in other words?

Comment: FYI, the return value from `maskFields()` is a promise with no enumerable fields because ALL `async` functions return a promise.  So, probably you think your jsonObject is empty because you're looking at the promise that `maskFields()` returns.  You have to use `.then()` or `await` on the return value from `maskFields()` to get its resolved value.  But, this is probably not your real problem, just a side affect of what you tried.

Comment: What is the real problem to be solved here?  Why do you want to make it asynchronous?  For what purpose?  That's the key to knowing what to suggest you do since  you can't actually make this code asynchronous in the main thread.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to make it asynchronous because the jsonObject I will actually be passing in to parse is extremely large, and so I do not want the function to run synchronously.

Comment: A `Promise`, or equivalently `async`/`await`, only schedules tasks within the same thread. They do not themselves allow any speedups. The reason Node uses them is because they allow the same thread doing other things while a thread would normally have to wait (e.g. during disk write, or web request). You cannot use either of those mechanisms to speed up code which is using the CPU at capacity, like your code does. As @jfriend00 said before, the only way to do this is to launch a new [thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) (or a new [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)).

Comment: Also, as @RobbyCornelissen notes, your code works fine: though `async`/`await` is misused, it does not make your return empty. Defining `jsonObject` as you did and then calling `await maskFields(jsonObject, ["FirstName", "LastName"])` returns exactly what one would expect.

Comment: @Rocker2982 What does "*the jsonObject I will actually be passing in to parse is extremely large*" mean exactly? How large is it? How long does a synchronous version of your code take to run (and why is that a problem)? And more importantly: where and how is the input object constructed, and what is your program doing with the processed object?

Comment: @Amadan "*[promises] allow the same thread doing other things while a thread would normally have to wait*" - I'd phrase that differently. It's the nodejs implementation of asynchronous disk writes and web requests etc that allows the thread to do other things instead of (or: "while") waiting. Promises, and `async`/`await` syntax, is used by nodejs programs only to make dealing with those asynchronous operations easier.

Comment: Are you trying to over engineer something before you actually have a problem? I would say if a large object is causing an issue than you probably want to figure out exactly what step in that code is causing the slowness. Pretty easy to comment out things and figure out what causes things to slow down.

Comment: This issue has now been resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @Rocker2982: You're still relatively inexperienced here, so let me suggest that proper etiquette would be to [edit] the post or add an answer explaining the resolution.  Did you take the advice of jfriend, Bergi, *et al*, and abandon the hope for asynrchonous code.?  Did you test to realize that it wasn't too slow for your case and drop the requirement? Did you create a worker thread?  Something else?

Comment: The package object-rewrite does exactly what you're looking for (and much more). Disclaimer: I'm the author

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> HOWEVER, the jsonObject being returned is completely empty.

Your `maskFields()` function returns a promise that resolves to your jsonObject.  It does not directly return your jsonObject.  You are probably looking at the promise and see no enumerable fields so you think you have an empty object.  But, in reality, you need to use `.then()` or `await` to get the resolved value from the promise that `maskFields()` returns.  Keep in mind that all `async` functions return a promise.

But, this isn't the real issue here at all.  You're misusing `async` and `await` on code that isn't asynchronous and isn't using promises.  So, `async` and `await` here are of no use at all.  They don't magically make something run asynchronously.

> I want to make it asynchronous because the jsonObject I will actually be passing in to parse is extremely large, and so I do not want the function to run synchronously.

As I've stated in the comments, you cannot make synchronous code into asynchronous code in nodejs using only Javascript.  The only actual asynchronous operations in nodejs are those who have an underlying library implementation in native code that uses either asynchronous OS APIs (networking in nodejs) or uses native threads to present an asynchronous appearance to Javascript code (file I/O in nodejs) or code that just calls existing asynchronous APIs.

Promises are just a tool to help you coordinate and track completion and errors in asynchronous operations.  They don't, by themselves, make anything asynchronous.  That can't make synchronous code run asynchronously.  And, `async/await` are just tools to help you use promises more easily.  `await` does absolutely nothing useful unless you are awaiting a promise that is tied to some underlying asynchronous operation.  Since you have no actual asynchronous code in your `maskFields()` function, neither promises or `async/await` are of any use.

So, you cannot just rewrite this in Javascript in nodejs in some way to make it non-blocking, asynchronous.

I can think of four possible options for you:

**1. Instrument your code to find out how long this actually takes to run.**  It's not complicated code.  It likely does not take long to run and you may be trying to solve a problem that isn't actually a problem.

**2. Write this code so that is can do small pieces of work in chunks**, allow other things to run, then do another chunk, etc...  To write code this way, you typically end up creating some sort of state machine object that keeps track of your state and then you do one small piece of work, pause briefly to allow any other things in the event queue to run (often with a short duration timer), then do another piece of work, etc... until done.  This allows you to make steady progress on a long running operation without blocking other things from running and doing their job.  You're essentially doing manual time slicing in the single main thread by making your code run only in short bursts.

**3. Move this code to a WorkerThread** and then communicate back the final result using the process messaging that WorkerThreads support.  In this way, you can run the synchronous implementation you already have (after you remove the promises and `async/await`) and it will not block the main thread.

**4. Move this code to a child process** which can also be a nodejs app if you want and communicate back the final result using the interprocess messaging that child processes support.  In this way, you can run the synchronous implementation you already have (after you remove the promises and `async/await`) and it will not block your nodejs process.